# Cannot set SQL_MODE to Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to set a persistent custom SQL MODE persistent to my server.
I added this line in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

```
[mysqld]
...
sql-mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

When I try to run mysql I get this error:

> 2020-06-03T09:49:24.567568Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value
>   'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
>   to 'sql_mode'. mysqld  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64
>   ((Ubuntu))

I tried to change `sql-mode` to `sql_mode` and remove the double quotes, but it doesn't change.

Comment: First do a spell check, no_engine_substitution, check if any sql-mode was removed in 8.0

Comment: I tried an empty list with double quotes `""` or only a single value, and it doesnt work.

Comment: it should be sql-mode='' (single-quotes), regarding your original problem NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER was removed in MySQL 8 hence the reason why it is not starting up.

Comment: I have tried without NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER but it still fails

Answer (score 13):

Just edit /etc/mysql/my.conf, removing "NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER". The result will be:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

It worked for me !

Answer (score 1):

There is some limitations to the behaviour of `sql_mode` in different linux environments.

Instead, you should uninstall `mysql` and replace it with
[MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/). A very good alternative to mysql server.
(As far as your concerned - this is mysql server, except it's package name)

To uninstall:

```sh
apt remove mysql mysqld mysql-server mysql-client
# note we do not purge this package, since we have databases with data in place.
```

Now install MariaDB - https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=focal--ubuntu_focal&mirror=icm&version=10.4

Sometime, the package maintainer already has MariaDB.
So, it's simple as:

`apt install mariadb mariadb-server mariadb-client`

I encourge you to backup your data beforehand, using `mysqldump` or other means.
But I would note that installing `maraidb` (as long as it will use the same dir for data) then all your databases, and tables will keep working normally.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer, but this is exactly what I have done!

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Ubuntu / Debian I am modifying the file:
`/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service`

`ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Then run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart mysql
```

changes to *.cnf files do nothing

[image: IMG]

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax is
sql-mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was solved by removing leading comma

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ",STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Changed to this:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is impossible to change *.cnf file in recent version.
Instead of, you can change mysql.service file .

```
/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --sql-mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Comment: Changing the `*.cnf` files is still possible, the option mentioned in the `mysql.service` just override them.